# Protected excel sheet is unprotected

Tags: passwords

Excel sheet protected in 2010 version unprotected without permission in 2013 and 2016.  Is it possible? How?

Comment: What do you mean by protection? The only secure form of protection is preventing *reading* the document by encrypting it (typically using a password). Other forms, such as "please don't edit/print this" flags are nothing more that polite requests to the application that can be ignored.

Comment: A created excel file password protected in 2010 (only particular cells, other cells can be edited).  When i received from the same template from 2013 user and other it is unprotected in my 2016 system. How it happened?

Comment: This is more of an Excel use question than a security question.